# SKSpriteNode doesn't disappear after removeFromParent() when Timer expires

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit, nstimer, skspritenode

In my game, I want that, every time my player touches an object, the screen turns white for about 0.5 seconds and then goes back to normal.

My code is:

```
private var crash: SKSpriteNode?

func crashadd(){
    crash = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Gameplay BG")
    crash?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    crash?.position.x = 0
    crash?.position.y = 0
    crash?.zPosition = 15
    mainCamera?.addChild(crash!)

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.1), target: self, selector: #selector(GameplayScene.removeCrash), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func removeCrash() {
    crash?.removeFromParent()
}
```

The problem is that the `crash` node sometimes doesn't remove itself.

Comment: I changed the title of your question to make it better describe the issue. Feel free to rollback my changes if you disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably calling `crashadd()` a second time before the timer expires. If you do that, it will overwrite the reference to the first `crash`, but not remove it from the screen. When the first timer expires, it will remove the current reference (the second `crash`). When the second timer expires, it will try to remove the same `crash` and silently fail. The first `crash` is never removed.

To solve this, you could put in a check to make sure there isn't already a `crash` on screen. Add this at the top of `crashadd()`:

```
guard crash == nil else {
    return
}
```

Now it will check that `crash` is empty. If it's not, the function returns without doing anything (since there is already a crash on screen).

Since crashing could happen multiple times, you should also add

```
crash = nil
```

at the end of `removeCrash()` to clear it for next time.

---

**Important note**

You should probably also look at where you're calling `crashadd()` multiple times and decide if that behavior is what you really want.

If the player is continuously touching an object, your code could be calling `crashadd()` every frame and throwing up a new `crash` as soon as the old one expires, giving the appearance that it is never removed. You'll need to make sure that your collision function is called only once for each collision and not repeatedly while the collision persists.

Comment: You should avoid using `Timer` all together, and use SpriteKit built in `SKAction`s to achieve what you want

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That's true, and it would make a good answer.